# appsettings.<env>.json is not getting used on server

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, aws-cloudformation, appsettings, aspnetcore-environment

I have defined below structure in my project.

```
    appsettings.json
      appsettings.development.json
      appsettings.prod.json
      appsettings.uat.json
```

Program.cs

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
    
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                    {
                        var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
                        config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
                    });
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

I want server to read stage specific appsettings file. But all environments are reading appsettings.json always.

Comment: I don't know if case-sensitivity is important - have you tried appsetings.Development.json?  Also the production environment is normally 'Production' not 'prod' - unless you are setting it manually somewhere.  Also: config cascades, so it will *always* read appsettings.json, and then *override* those with subsequent config options.

Comment: In yml file, i have defined env mappings
```
  AppEnvMap:
    legacy:
      dev: Development
      qa: qa
      uat: uat
      prod: prod
```

Comment: EnvironmentName and appsettings file name IS case-sensitive (on Linux, not on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

Are you copying your appsetting.json to the output directory?

```
<ItemGroup>
      <None Update="appsettings.Development.json">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </None>         
      <None Update="appsettings.P.json">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </None>
    </ItemGroup>
```

If you want to use environment variables you should register them with
.AddEnvironmentVariables()

like this:

```
public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment environment)
{
    _environment = environment ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(environment));

    Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(environment.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment.EnvironmentName}.json", true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();
}
```

I think .NET 5 and onward does this for you as long as DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT is set. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.host.createdefaultbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-6.0

Comment: {environment.EnvironmentName} is a variable that needs to come from somewhere. And you'll need to do AddEnvironmentVariables() to be able to read from environment variables. Also I think it's pretty safe to add .AddJsonFile("appsettings.development.json", false, true)